# Forms won't submit

Tags: theme-development, forms

I have a brand new theme that I just built out using _s's (underscores) that won't submit forms. Here are the errors I get in the console:

On submit:

```
Uncaught Typeerror: cannot read property: 'checkValidity' of undefined
```

Followed by:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "about:blank”.
```

Steps I’ve taken:

1. Verify that WP is able to send emails by submitting ‘reset password’
2. Installed a plugin that verify’s emails can be sent
3. Narrowed it down to the theme itself because *I am* able to submit forms when twenty thirteen is installed
4. the problem occurs in both Contact Form 7 and Gravity Forms, so isn't either of them
5. I uninstalled all plugins and I’m still not able to submit

Anybody have an idea of what could be causing this in my theme?

Comment: How should we know? Not enough information. No code relates to the problem you've provided.

Comment: You should consider showing (A) the form code and (B) the code used to process the form. [Have you seen this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7386922/376483) on a similar topic on SO? Without seeing your code it's actually a guessing game. If it's just about Contact Form 7 and Gravity Forms, then it's off topic. If it's about for e.g. the default contact form, then we can proceed. Can you confirm that?

Comment: I provided 1. The problem I was experiencing. 2.The error messages I was receiving, and 3. The steps I've taken so far to resolve the issue. That sounds like plenty of information to me, but instead I get downvoted. I'll stay away from these forums. Good luck with the 'community' here.

Comment: Thanks, kaiser. You're comment was helpful in telling me what kind of further information to provide. I still can't figure out why I would be downvoted instead of helped along like you have done. The nature of StackExchange I guess. Sad, really.

Comment: Well the first step would be to find out what `checkValidity` is doing and where it is.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving the issue. In case anybody run across this in the future, here's what it was:

I narrowed the issue down to the template itself by stripping out all of the markup on the page, which allowed the form to work as normal.

I then narrowed it down to the `<form>` tag that was causing the conflict. Essentially, the GravityForm generated `<form>` tag and the one I had in my template were clashing. I should have seen the double `<form>` tags, but missed it.

I’m all set now.